# Facebook 'publish_actions' permission for android app

Tags: facebook, android-facebook

I have written a android code through which i am posting a description about app on user's wall. For that i have submitted the app for review with Publish Actions permission request.

But Facebook rejected it saying...

**I was unable to reproduce your publish_actions permission because the post hadn't shared on my test user's Facebook wall.**

i don't understand, without publish_action permission how is that possible to post message on the user wall, if its possible then why we required the publish_action permission.

please help somebody,

and one more thing i have already test my code with another app which already have the publish_action permission , and my code post message successfully to the user.

please help somebody, urgently required.

Comment: You can ask anyone that have a role on the app for any permission. You only need to get reviewed when you are going to ask other people than people that have a role on the app for the permission. And you posting a description on the user's wall sounds like it would be against Facebook Platform Policy so you probably want to read that before you submit

Comment: @WizKid thanks for your reply. i think you don't understand my question. i already submit that app for the review but Facebook not approved it. and for posting message of the user wall required public_action permission. i already test my app for the test user, its working well and also posted the message of the test user wall. but Facebook still saying the post hadn't shared on my test user's Facebook wall. , for posting other people wall than people that have a role on the app required permission, i know that, that's why we required publish_action permission. but Facebook not approved it.